# issue understanding rootviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am not talking regarding navigationviewcontroller. A normal app with two or three views, the first view which is shown when app is started is known as rootviewcontroller. Now I want to switch to 2nd view I used transitionfromview and released first view, now second view is the rootviewcontroller correct?

And is it true if I switch to second view using addsubview and removing first view? The second view will become rootviewcontroller.

Right now I don't want to dive any other topic like memory etc. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a time when an app is run the first view whatever say name rootViewController or any thing else, the view which add as a window's rootView is a root view of app. now you say that when you tap from first view to second view at that time also the root view is first view and second view is the **child** view of first. root view remains there as it is. if you add your second view controller in to window's root view controller than at that time the root is second view controller